# How to assign NULL value to variable when no corresponding value in JSON Extractor

Tags: jmeter

I have the below JSON. Data of errorMessage is assigned to the variable pError if it exists.Otherwise it should assign null or no data found.

{"data":{"devTransactions":[{"transactionId":"ae6deb12c356","status":"Failed","details":{"value":427,
"error":{"stage":"MANAGE","errorCode":"ERR021001","errorMessage":"Failed to start"},
"hcigId":"28fccffdf291","deviceId":"571a71b05c50"},"cancelledBy":""},
{"transactionId":"9f486bc9b111","status":"COMPLETED","details":{"empid":"1000","deptId":"230"},
"cancelledBy":""}]},"success":true,"statusCode":200}

Later I want to assign pError to a string array and fetch the values.My array size is fixed say 50. Im getting error now when fetch it with a loop because data doesn't exist in that particular index of array.

How to assign null or no data found to the variable pError if no data or json element found?

String strError = "${pError_ALL}";
String[] error = strError.split(",");

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but one thing is obvious: your Json Path expression will not match any or `errorMessage` attribute values because your `devTransactions` is a [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp)

[image]

In order to get error messages values you need to amend your expression to look like:

```
$.data.devTransactions[*].details.error.errorMessage
```

[image]

Prior to writing some code (which is incorrectly referencing JMeter Variables by the way, you should amend it to use [`vars` shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) like `String strError = vars.get("pError_ALL");`) I would recommend double checking your `pError_ALL` variable value using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler).